# This jQuery code keeps on sliding down and sliding up the "over2" pane when mouseover on it

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#li1').mouseover(function(){

        $(".over2").slideDown("slow");
        $(".over").hide();
    });
    $('#li1').mouseout(function(){

        $(".over2").slideUp("fast");
        $(".over").show();
    });
});
```

the html of this is right here!!

```
<li id="li1" class="news_tabs">
   <img src="Images/images.jpg" height="290" width="200" />
   <div class="over">
      <h5>The blackberry Launched in</h5>
   </div>
   <div id="over2" class="over2">
      <p>The total discription The total discription The
        total discription The total
        discription The total discription </p>
   </div>
</li>

<li class="news_tabs"> this is two</li>
<li class="news_tabs">this is three</li>
<li class="news_tabs"> this is four</li>
```

there is a image ,  what i want to do is-> when a user mouseover the image the heading hides and a short discription slides from the top , and when the mouseis out then again the heading appears and the discription slides up.
but here when the mouse is on the discription which slided down, the discription slides up and down again and again till mouse is out... please help

how to stop the sliding down and up uncontrollably by this code?

Comment: Please include your HTML code and perhaps a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: <li id="li1" class="news_tabs"><img src="Images/images.jpg" height="290" width="200" /><div class="over"> <h5>The blackberry Launched in</h5></div><div id="over2" class="over2"><p> The total discription The total discription The total discription The total discription The total discription </p> </div> </li>
<li class="news_tabs"> this is two</li>
<li class="news_tabs">this is three </li>
<li class="news_tabs"> this is four</li>

Comment: In your question, please.  As you can see, code is unreadable in comments.

Comment: Do not dump code into comments.  Edit your original post.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sparky672 , it worked fine , but because of my curiuosity can you explain why this happens when we use mouseover and mouse out and works fine in case of hove and mouseenter ?

Comment: mouseenter is triggered totally different than mouseover.  The latter fires off repeatedly as long as you're over the element.  mouseenter only fires once when you enter.  I undeleted my answer for reference.

Comment: the code is running fine now but i need that whenever the mouse is out the animation should stop at that moment rather it continues and completes ... i need to remove this thing...

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your HTML or a demo so I'm not positive this will solve it, but typically the result you describe is caused by using `mouseover`/`mouseout` rather than `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`.

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#li1').mouseenter(function() {
        $(".over2").slideDown("slow");
        $(".over").hide();
    });
    $('#li1').mouseleave(function() {
        $(".over2").slideUp("fast");
        $(".over").show();
    });

});
```

And alternatively, the shorthand version uses [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#li1').hover(
        function() {
            $(".over2").slideDown("slow");
            $(".over").hide();
        },
        function() {
            $(".over2").slideUp("fast");
            $(".over").show();
        }
    );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
this will work for how many `li` elements you want

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsbin.com/uqemic/2/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('ul.news_tabs li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.over').stop().fadeTo(300,0);
    $(this).find('.over2').stop().slideDown();
  },function(){
    $(this).find('.over').stop().fadeTo(300,1);
    $(this).find('.over2').stop().slideUp();    
  });
  
});
```

I changed your HTML too, as I have noticed that you had the intention to name EVERY `li` element assigning a different `ID`. Don't do that. DO like:

```
<ul class="news_tabs">    
    <li>
       <img src="Images/images.jpg" height="290" width="200" />
       <div class="over">
          <h5>1 The blackberry Launched in</h5>
       </div>
       <div class="over2">
          <p>The total discription The total discription The
            total discription The total
            discription The total discription </p>
       </div>
    </li>


    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>


</ul>
```